# How to support the "increase contrast" option under the Accessibility > Display

Tags: macos, accessibility

- Xcode 9.2
- macOS High Sierra (10.13.3)

macOS gives users a choice to "increase contrast".

[image: increase contrast under accessibility display settings]

I am trying to support this within a macOS app.
Specifically, I want to adjust the [fill of NSBox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsbox/1429797-fillcolor)

What's the way to do it?

**Update**

There is a `NSWorkspace.accessibilityDisplayOptionsDidChangeNotification` notification however, it doesn't appear to fire.

[Sample Project](https://github.com/qnoid/AccessibilityDisplayOptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSWorkspace.accessibilityDisplayOptionsDidChangeNotification` fires when option changes. The only thing is, it fires in `NSWorkspace`'s notification center. Not in the default one.

```
NSWorkspace.shared.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(accessibilityDisplayOptionsDidChange(_:)), name: NSWorkspace.accessibilityDisplayOptionsDidChangeNotification, object: NSWorkspace.shared)
```

Then you have to use `NSWorkspace.shared.accessibilityDisplayShouldIncreaseContrast` property in your code to alter the appearance of your UI when necessary.